# Directory.Getfiles().OrderBy(f=>f.Name) Name is not shown by default

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When I use the following, `Name` does not appear by default neither by date.

```
OrderBy (f=>f.Name)
```

Please help.

Environment:

- Visual Studio 2012
- c#
- using System.Linq and System.Data.Entity.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's because the method `Directory.GetFiles()` returns an array of string containing the files' full names

Source : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> Return Value
>   Type: System.String[]
>
> An array of the full names (including paths) for the files in the
>   specified directory, or an empty array if no files are found.

If you do want to have only file's name (and not full name), you can do the following way :

```
Directory.GetFiles().Select(fullPath => new FileInfo(fullPath)).Select(f => f.Name);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer my friend, f.Name is able in this way but this code put my txt file in another path that it do not exist :/